# Custom Segue class perform method called, action doesn't do anything

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uiviewcontroller, segue

I'm trying to create a custom segue between the `ViewController` (first view) and the `BrowserController` (second view).

Currently I have...

**CustomSegue.h:**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface CustomSegue : UIStoryboardSegue

@end
```

**CustomSegue.m:**

```
    #import "CustomSegue.h"

@implementation CustomSegue

- (void)perform {

    NSLog(@"Perform Method Running");

    UIViewController *ViewController = (UIViewController *) self.sourceViewController;
    UIViewController *BrowserController = (UIViewController *) self.destinationViewController;

    NSLog(@"Starting duration...");

    [UIView transitionWithView:ViewController.navigationController.view duration:0.2
    options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionFlipFromLeft
    animations:^{

                NSLog(@"Animation section");

                [ViewController.navigationController pushViewController:BrowserController animated:NO];

                }
                    completion:NULL];

    NSLog(@"Performance Method Completion");

}
```

Nothing happens when I click the button to go to the next view.

I set the view segue to "custom" (CTRL drag) and defined my class as "CustomSegue". I see there are two "custom" options to select after CTRL and dragging- I have tried both of these just in case (and I re-defined my class both times), still the problem persists. I also used an `NSLog` and saw that the `perform` method is being called, I have no errors, and yet the button still does not perform the segue (or ANY segue) to the next view.

**The button that triggers the segue**

```
- (IBAction)browserButton:(id)sender
```

This is the last area I could narrow it down to... do I need to add anything to this `IBAction` to tell it to use the new segue?

Comment: Fixed- never realized I can highlight the code after I've pasted it then hit the {} :)

Comment: You get the 2 controllers with segue.sourceViewController and segue.destinationViewController

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to do anything to the IBAction. It seems like everything should be working fine and you've tried everything- I recommend you delete the work (or rollback if you use github) and start it over again. Start from the point right before you added your `CustomSegue` class and be sure to retype the code (you never know, sometimes you catch small details).

Goodluck.

Answer (score 2):

What Xcode is telling you is precisely right: `self` (which is of type `CustomSegue`, of course) has neither `ViewController` nor `BrowserController` property. This is because you did not declare these properties in your `CustomSegue` class, and its base class `UIStoryboardSegue` does not have them either.

There are two solutions that you could try - using built-in properties directly, or wrapping them in properties with the names that you desire.

Here is the first approach:

```
UIViewController *ViewController = (UIViewController *) self.sourceViewController;
UIViewController *BrowserController = (UIViewController *) self.destinationViewController;
```

Here is the second approach:

```
-(UIViewController*) ViewController {
    return self.sourceViewController;
}
-(UIViewController*) BrowserController {
    return self.destinationViewController;
}
```

The first approach is faster to implement, but it may be less readable. The second approach requires more typing, but it gives the source and the destination controllers the names that better describe their roles in your application. The choice is up to you.

Comment: That fixed the error, but I still have another problem... please check my edited post.
+1'd :)

Comment: @Collin Do you know if the `perform` method gets called? Try adding `NSLog` inside the method to see if it gets called.

Comment: @Collin Look at your `transitionWithView` then, and see if anything in that `animations:` block is set to `nil`, i.e. `src`, `src.navigationController`, `dst`, etc.

Comment: How do I access transitionWithView? I don't have that reference in my xcode project anywhere, but I don't get an error by using it.

Comment: @Collin Just add `NSLog` calls to your `animations:` block, printing the various values that you expect to be non-nil before the call of `pushViewController:` method.

Comment: Everything calls correctly... the last thing I can narrow it down to is the `ibaction` on the button as `- (IBAction)browserButton:(id)sender ` do I need to extend anything here?

Comment: @Collin Something is not calling correctly, because you do not see a transition :) Try changing `[src.navigationController pushViewController:dst animated:NO];` to `[ViewController.navigationController pushViewController:BrowserController animated:NO];` and see what happens.